# How to write a safe stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I want to write a safe simple stored procedure which will select some columns from database table based on some parameters given to stored procedure.

I have tried two ways of writing the stored procedure.

1st way as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPBasic
    @id int,
    @value int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Id, name, design 
    FROM SimpleTable
    WHERE ID = @id AND value = @value;
END
GO
```

2nd way as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPBasic
    @id int,
    @value int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'SELECT Id, name, design FROM SimpleTable
                 WHERE ID = @id AND value = @value';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@id int, @value int', @id,@value;
END
GO
```

For both the cases I run the script as:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = SPBasic
        @id = N'11',
        @value = 1;drop table test

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

And in both the cases the temporary table test which I created for test purpose is getting deleted.

So, I would like to know what could be the safe code for this purpose?

Comment: how about not include the drop table command? Confused as to what youre meaning

Comment: You are not passing `1;drop table test` to the procedure. You are invoking the procedure with `EXEC`, and then executing a separate `DROP TABLE` command. This is not an example of SQL injection, and there is nothing the procedure can do to prevent this. If the stored procedure took a `VARCHAR` parameter, and malfunctioned when you passed `'1;drop table test'` as a string, then you could have SQL injection. A procedure that doesn't use `EXEC` is immune to SQL injection, assuming it is called by the client in the proper way (for example, in .NET by using `CommandType.StoredProcedure`).

Comment: If you are worrying about injection, please post how `EXEC SPBasic @id = N'11', @value = 1;drop table test` is generated. You need to protect this EXEC, not the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Since both your stored procedures take integer parameters, there is no possibility of an SQL injection attack. If the 2nd procedure took a string ( varchar ) parameter, then an SQL injection attack would be a possibility.